# Python sys.stdin.buffer size detection

Tags: python, pipe

I'm trying to execute a Python script from a Qt application and to communicate with the script via standard input and output (as one would do via common Unix pipes). My calling code stub looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QProcess process;
  QTimer timer;
  QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&process]() {
    qDebug() << "<<o" << process.readAllStandardOutput();
  });
  QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [&process]() {
    qDebug() << "<<e" << process.readAllStandardError();
  });
  QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::started, [&process] {
    qDebug() << "Process name" << process.program() << process.processId();
  });
  QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&process]() {
    qDebug() << process.state();
    QByteArray ba("12345");
    qDebug() << ">>" << ba;
    process.write(ba);
    if (!process.waitForBytesWritten())
      qDebug() << process.errorString();
  });
  QObject::connect(&a, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, [&]() {
    process.terminate();
    process.kill();
  });
  process.start("python3", {"main.py"});
  //  process.start("cat", QStringList{});
  timer.start(2000);
  a.exec();
  process.terminate();
  process.kill();
  return 0;
}
```

And my Python script is shown below:

```
import sys, time

def process_data(data):
    size=len(data)
    if size %2:
        print(f'Odd, {size}',data) 
    else:
        print(f'Even, {size}',data)
    sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        data=sys.stdin.buffer.read(5)
        if len(data):
            process_data(data)
        else:
            print('.')
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

The thing is that I want to have my script react on any incoming buffer, much like a cat command does. When I comment out the line calling my script and uncomment the one calling the cat command, each time I send a buffer, I receive a reply, which is what I want. But when I'm calling a Python script, I have no means of detecting incoming buffer size that I know of. Explicitly setting a value in a sys.stdin.buffer.read command allows me not to wait for an EOF, but I want to receive a buffer without knowing its size in advance. In Qt I would achieve such behavior by calling readAll() method of a QIODevice. Is there a way of doing the same in Python?

I have tried calling sys.stdin.buffer.read() without any arguments, expecting it to behave like QIODevice::readAll() - producing a buffer with all the data read so far. But obviously it produces nothing until it receives an EOF. I hope there is a kind of method that yields a size of buffer received so that I could write:

```
size=stdin.buffer.bytesReceived()
data=stdin.buffer.read(size)
```

yet such method seems to be missing.

Does anyone know of any solution to this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to read *exactly* as much data as available, all at once? Even the `cat` program you want to mimic doesn't do that.

Comment: There are two parts of the system: master and slave. Master calls a slave and feeds it some data, with slave having no knowledge of these data in advance. So master starts the slave once and then the processing goes as following: master receives some data from somewhere else (from a device, actually, but it doesn't matter here), then master feeds the data to the slave. Slave processes these data and returns a result.

cat command does exactly this, with the exception that it doesn't perform any processing and just returns the data received.

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v9.1/src/cat.c#L154) for GNU cat, you'll see the `simple_cat` routine makes no attempt to determine how much data is available. It just does `safe_read (input_desc, buf, bufsize)`, which is basically the equivalent of calling `sys.stdin.buffer.read` with a fixed buffer size argument in Python.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a proper communication protocol, with a way to determine where individual messages start and end - you seem to be trying to use "read all available data" as a substitute for "read one message".

Comment: The difference is that safe_read returns number of bytes actually read. If I send 8 bytes with buffer size of 10, safe_read reads these 8 bytes and tells the calling code that it has read 8 bytes. Contrary, sys.stdin.buffer.read waits for given number of bytes to arrive, so when I send 8 bytes, sys.stdin.buffer.read doesn't give me these 8 bytes - it waits for whole 10 to arrive.

Comment: Checking... oh. `sys.stdin.buffer` is a BufferedReader, not a FileIO. I was thinking of `sys.stdin.buffer.raw`. That won't wait for 10 bytes. (Alternatively, you can use `read1(bufsize)` instead of `read(bufsize)`.)

Comment: And about the communication protocol: I used to implement similar protocols in C++/Qt, and the most reliable way of implementing them was to provide [start and] stop sequence. But in this case I still need to read all data available and look for the stop sequence within.

Comment: Oh! sys,stdin,buffer.raw seems to be what I'm looking for! Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Yep, it did help! I'm marking the problem as solved.

Comment: @KirillDidkovsky If you resolved the problem, post the solution for other users who might run into a similar issue in the future.

Comment: @Dimitar, I have already done so two hours ago by adding updates to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by changing `sys.stdin.buffer.read` line to:

```py
data = sys.stdin.buffer.raw.read(20000)
```

This also works:

```py
data = sys.stdin.buffer.read1(20000)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as [edit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75218737/2) and [edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75218737/3) to the question [Python sys.stdin.buffer size detection [solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75218737/python-sys-stdin-buffer-size-detection-solved) by the OP [Kirill Didkovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707126/kirill-didkovsky) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>